# How to display location text (place details) on Google Street View Panorama?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, google-street-view

I am working on a project related to applying AR in an Android app. I have location coordinates of my current location in street-view. Then I found the location coordinates of the nearby places of my current location (JSON parsed data) using Google Place API. Now I wish to display them on Google Street View's panorama view. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Google Street View provides panoramic 360-degree views from designated roads throughout its coverage area.
The coverage available through the Google Maps Android API v2 is the same as that for the Google Maps app on your Android device. You can read more about Street View and see the supported areas on an interactive map, at About Street View.
The StreetViewPanorama class models the Street View panorama in your application. Within your UI, a panorama is represented by a StreetViewPanoramaFragment or StreetViewPanoramaView object.
Introduction video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKgVkdTcsULfTIIsKz4n-I8&v=VjEfpl9_iDU
Official Code example: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo

Here is the good tutorial for step by step adding google street view in any android app.
http://www.quicktips.in/how-to-add-integrate-google-street-view-panorama-view-in-our-android-application/